# Use idangerous.swiper.js on Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, swipe

Markup :

```
<ol>
     <li>
           <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <img class="listitempage" data-url="" src=""/>
                    </div>
                     <div class="pagination"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Script for Slider

```
<script>
        var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            pagination: '.pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            mode: 'vertical'
        });
```

Images are dynamically loaded one after another. I want to swipe that images. But unable to do so. Please help.

Comment: "But unable to do so"... because?

Comment: there is no error. But i cant swipe.

Comment: info like what plugin you're using, the type of device you're testing it on would be useful...

Comment: i am using swiper plugin. i am testing on iphone 5

Comment: checkout my answer, hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure that the relevant plugin files (both the .js and .css) are being called correctly like this (taken from the [Swiper plugin documentation](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php)):

```
<head>
    <!-- other stuff here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_css/idangerous.swiper.css">
    <script defer src="path_to_js/idangerous.swiper-2.x.min.js"></script>
    <!-- other stuff here -->
</head>
```

If this is ok and your code is really what you have posted, then you might not see it working because you haven't actually added any content to swipe.

I have tried it out here and it is working perfectly for me on an iPhone 4S and a Samsung Galaxy S3 (both using Chrome), try it out here: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Xnj/)**.

Comment: thankyou for your reply. Img src are not fixed. They are dynamically loaded from js which inturn gets from json image paths.

Comment: are you actually seeing the list of images rendered on the resulting page? you should see them all in the code, if you don't, then the issue might be with the json call, and not the swipe plugin, but that would be a completely different topic...

Comment: i can see the images render on page. i create an array to show image on src attribute.

 <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <img class="listitempage" data-url="" src=""/>
                    </div>

Comment: try to get rid of `<ol>` and `<li>` elements, also put the pagination outside of the `swiper-container`, just for testing purposes...

Comment: ...and the individual images should be wrapped inside of `swiper-slide` and being siblings of each other... in one word: follow the documentation and it should work, otherwise you're doing something wrong... you may send me the url you have this on so that I can have a look...

Comment: I am using bellow javascript to get images from json and dispay on src attribute of src


$(document).ready(function () {
     
    var tpl = $('.swiper-wrapper');

    for (var i = data.products.docs.length; i > 0; i--) {
  var list = tpl.clone().appendTo(tpl.parent());     
        var spec = data.products.docs[i-1];

        list.find('.swiper-slide img').attr('src', spec.image);
    
    }
  });

Comment: don't add it as a comment but update your original question! make sure you annotate it as an edit, otherwise my answer will become obsolete...